# Expression for "The time period in which I started working in my current workplace"

Tags: phrase-requests

James started to work at place X since 20th February 2019.

Which phrase should be used to refer to the time period which is the beginning of his work at that workplace?

For example (the following is bad English):
"At the beginning of my work at X I used to joke with lots of colleagues."
I seek to replace most of "At the beginning of my work at X" with a phrase.

Comment: "When I first started working at X".

Answer (score 1):

“When I first worked at X” seems to fit your need in your second example.

The first example has not quite the same structure. It might be expressed as “James first worked at X from 20th ...” or “... first worked at X after 20th ...”

I prefer *after* to *since* because *since* is often used to imply that whatever started at some time is still happening. And that is not necessarily the case here: James or I may have left the job.

Comment: So he first worked at X in 1990, and worked there again in 2001?

Comment: +1. I was hoping for a single word which described it. Something like "On my Y at X, ...". Such that Y is the single word phrase.

Comment: Perhaps you were looking for something like "On my employment at X, I had to give up weekday marathon running". It is an abbreviated form of "On (the occasion of) my first employment  at X".